# Undefined symbols for architecture i386

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, xcode4

i am getting this error it si hard to explain thats why i am attaching the image
[image]

this error accure when i am adding I class Base64.h

Comment: Just a thought - You appear to be compiling an iphone program on a mac. I don't think you're supposed to have i386 defined. ie. there are no libraries for the function specified on the target platform. What is the code you're  writing?

Comment: Do you have Base64.m or Base64.c in your project ?

Comment: @PreetSangha the same copy of my project working fine in other mac

Comment: @PaulR ia m Base64.h Base64.m both and iam including Base64.h

Comment: @FaheemRajput - Could be that each machine has different environment settings. You should check that too. Can you get a verbose or chatty build where the whole build env is dumped as text and then compare these two?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the file `Base64.m` is not properly added to your project. It doesn't get compiled so it's missing when the final image is being linked.

Make sure the file `Base64.m` is the same kind of project member as `FirstViewController.m` (similar location, similar settings etc.).

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution it is amy just a trick but i create the both base64 h and m files again with different name and then use it that time it works 
thank to you